# Collections.synchronizedList vs Vector

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I would like to use collection classes for adding,removing and retrieving objects in multiple thread.

`Collections.synchronizedList` and `Vector` both classes are thread safe. Does any tell me the difference between `Collections.synchronizedList` and `Vector` and explain that when should I use `Vector` and `Collections.synchronizedList`?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vector+vs+synchronized+arraylist would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Here are few words on why Vector is an obsolete/deprecated class: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Generally about their difference: [In java, Vector and Collections.synchronizedList are all synchronized, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932034/in-java-vector-and-collections-synchronizedlist-are-all-synchronized-whats-th)

Comment: +1 Use Vector when you have to because you are using an old API which expects it. Otherwise use List.